# pullback map on k-tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds, tensors

This question was asked in an assignment of k-tensors and I struck on them. I am having a hard time solving questions related to pullback maps. I have followed my notes which are based on the textbook John lee's introduction to smooth manifolds.

> Question: Let V and W be the vector spaces of dimension m and n respectively and let $T: V\to W$ be a linear transformation of rank r. Let $T^{*}: L^{k} (W) \to L^{k}(V)$ be the corresponding pullback map on k-tensors.  Compute the dimension of $Ker(T^{*})$.

Attempt: Definition: Suppose that $L : V\to  W$ is a linear transformation, and that $\alpha \in T^k(W^{*})$. We then define the pullback tensor $L^{*} \alpha$ by
$(L^{*}(\alpha))(v_1,...,v_k) = \alpha(L(v_1),L(v_2),...,L(v_k))$.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to understand how exactly should I use the definition to proceed towards the dimension of $Ker(T^{*})$.

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Do you know any conditions which would imply that $\alpha(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_k)=0$ for some vectors in $W$?

Comment: @CF I am sorry but I am not able to recollect this condition. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: The condition I had in mind, which I though might be relevant was that  $\alpha(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_k)=0$ if any $w_i=0.$ This follows by multilinearity.

Comment: Of course, this is not a necessary condition, but I thought it might be a good place to start. Since you can get some bounds and see where the particulars might come in.

Comment: @CF Sorry but I am still not able to make much progress. Sorry for replying late due to my poor health.